# Cannot install Android app using WSO2 app system management

Tags: android, wso2, wso2-iot

I successfully installed WSO2 **iot-server3.1.0**. I **enrolled my android device successfully**. I can see my device status and logs on https://localhost:9443/devicemgt/device/android?id=(someid).

The image below is a snapshot of my device status.

[image: figure 1.0]

Meanwhile I managed to **publish a custom .apk** into the wso2 local server store. From the store I can access the application and then **install it on different enrolled devices**.

This is where I get (see picture:)
[image: figure 2.0]
Then I selected the desired enrolled device by user and press install. I do not get any errors and so the **application should start installing on the selected devices** **but it DOES NOT HAPPEN AS EXPECTED**. The application is not being installed. As you can see in figure 1.0 in the logs, **INSTALL_APPLICATION remains IN_PROGRESS**. I proceed install 15 hours ago. What is happening? Any hint is welcome. Thanks!

I followed the following:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O5UPy8XfaFY&lc=z23dcvywblayvlyzt04t1aokg12r1aunvhugyhklc2ehrk0h00410.1513229853059086
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voBWYk0Zm6I

*** EDIT ***

While watching throug my android device logs (while pressing install from server) I observed the folowing link: http://192.168.43.107:8280/api/device-mgt/android/v1.0/devices/8f12df164e574651/pending-operations. The request returns the following xml:

```
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
<script>...</script>
<am:code>404</am:code>
<am:type>Status report</am:type>
<am:message>Runtime Error</am:message>
<am:description>No matching resource found for given API Request</am:description>
</am:fault>
```

Also I get this on server:

```
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.exception.APIManagerPublisherException: feign.RetryableException: Connection refused: connect executing POST https://localhost:9443/client-registration/v0.11/register
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherServiceImpl.publishAPI(APIPublisherServiceImpl.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherStartupHandler.publishAPIs(APIPublisherStartupHandler.java:97)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherStartupHandler.access$500(APIPublisherStartupHandler.java:30)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherStartupHandler$1.run(APIPublisherStartupHandler.java:69)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: feign.RetryableException: Connection refused: connect executing POST https://localhost:9443/client-registration/v0.11/register
        at feign.FeignException.errorExecuting(FeignException.java:67)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:104)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
        at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.register(Unknown Source)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.integration.client.OAuthRequestInterceptor.apply(OAuthRequestInterceptor.java:84)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.targetRequest(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:158)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:88)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
        at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.apisGet(Unknown Source)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherServiceImpl.publishAPI(APIPublisherServiceImpl.java:53)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1316)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1291)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
        at feign.Client$Default.convertAndSend(Client.java:133)
        at feign.Client$Default.execute(Client.java:73)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:97)
        ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the following value to the URL you are accessing the server.

In IOT_HOME/conf/app-manager.xml

```
<Config name="AppDownloadURLHost">%http%</Config>
```

Comment: and change it to what specifically? the documentation does not refer to app-manager.xml. can you post a link with a more detailed documentation on how to setup the server properly? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile Android agent changing APP_MANAGER_HOST property to https://192.168.43.107:9443 use Shift Ctrl F to find all occurence